# How I can plot approximate solutions of a boundary value problem using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, numerical-integration, numerical-analysis

I have tried plotting the approximate solutions for boundary value problem using my below code such that I have tried `ezplot()` command `ezplot(sym(i),[x(i) x(i+1)])` but this doesn't work.

I received this error

> Index exceeds the number of array elements (3)

The approximate solutions that I have after compilation are : `-1.33,-1.1660,-1.3320`. The code below solves the boundary value problem  `-u''+6u=-(4x^2+6)exp(x^2), u(-1)=u(1) = 0`

**Boundary Value problem code:**

```
N=4;
n=N-1;
a=-1;b=1;h=(b-a)/N ;
x=linspace(a,b,N+1);
x=x(2:end-1);
A=diag(ones(n,1));
B=diag(ones(n-1,1),-1);
C=diag(ones(n-1,1),1);

K1=1/h*(2*A-B-C);
K2=h*(4*A+B+C)
K=K1+K2;
K(1,1)=K(2,2)/2;
K(n,n)=K(1,1);

f=@(x) (-4*x^2-6)*exp(x^2);
b=zeros(n,1);

for i=1:n
    b(i)=h*f(x(i));
end

b(1)=h/2*f(x(1));
b(n)=h/2*f(x(n));
U=pinv(K)*b
```

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve? Why do you say it “doesn’t work”? Does that mean you have a error, or wrong results? What are the results you expect to get? Please see [ask].

Comment: What are you trying to do with `ezplot(sym(i),[x(i) x(i+1)])`? Do you know anything about plotting in Matlab?